# Angularjs calling factory changes $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

first of all thank you for your time.

I'm having this issue, and I don't know really well why it is.

```
main
.controller('MainSelectsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, $translate, $ionicHistory, Auth, ajax, Data, sections, utils) {

    var filterBarInstance;

    _initController = function () {
        $rootScope.icon_sections = _searchIcon($ionicHistory.currentStateName().split(".")[1])
        if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            PARENT = $scope.$parent
        }
       }
        ...

       _initController();
```

and

```
main
.controller('MainSelectsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, $translate, $ionicHistory, Auth, ajax, Data, sections, utils) {

    var filterBarInstance;

    _initController = function () {
        $rootScope.icon_sections = _searchIcon($ionicHistory.currentStateName().split(".")[1])
        if ($scope.isLogged) {
            PARENT = $scope.$parent
    }
       }
    ....
       initController();
```

If I use $scope.isLogged, PARENT is ok and I can access later to a desired method.
If I use Auth.isLoggedIn() I don't know  why but $scope.$parent changes.

Here is the factory auth:

```
angular.module('auth.services', [])
.factory('Auth', function () {
   var _user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['session']);
   var setUser = function (session) {
      _user = session;
      window.localStorage['session'] = JSON.stringify(_user);
   }

   return {
      setUser: setUser,
      isLoggedIn: function () {
         return _user ? true : false;
      },
      getUser: function () {
         return _user;
      },
      logout: function () {
         window.localStorage.removeItem("session");
         _user = null;
      }
   }
});
```

Thank you very much

Comment: My biggest question is: why do you want to access parent scope? This is rather a big no-no.

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking or what `parent changes` actually means

Comment: The problem is that, I need to call a method declared in parents view, and if I do $scope.isLogged it works and I can execute it, if I do with Auth.isLoggedIn() I don't know but in $scope.$parent I can execute that method, It returns to me undefined because I check if the function exists.

Comment: I don't want to access the parent scope, I want to access a function in parent view and execute it. 
I have a select that changes the item or section in the app, and the function is allways in parent controller.